# Конвертация YAW PITCH ROLL в траекторию для UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

У меня есть массив данных (YPR) снятый с показаний гироскопа при его движении по определенной траектории (примерно по 100 значений на секунду).
Я знаю скорость перемещения данного датчика на записанном отрезке пути.
Тоесть, теоретически я могу построить снятую мной траекторию, внутри UE4 с помощью генерации сплайна, если переведу массив (YPR)  в массив 3D координат (XYZ).
Вопрос в следующем - какие вы можете посоветовать способы такой конвертации.
Все предложения и исправления моего подхода, с радостью принимаются)!
(Желательны примеры на C++)

Comment: Опишите подробнее форматы `YPR` и `XYZ`, тогда можно будет говорить о какой-то конвертации предметно.

Comment: YPR - это углы поворота, они могут помочь построить траекторию только в том случае, если вам известно, что вектор скорости всегда привязан к этим углам . В общем случае это не так. Если вам известен только модуль скорости, задача не имеет решения в общем случае. Если вам известен вектор скорости (т.е. скорость по координатам XYZ), тогда вам не нужны координаты YPR: если известна скорость и время, в течении которого она условно не менялась, можно посчитать расстояние, пройденное за это время.

Comment: спасибо за информацию